# How can I list information about a thread/LWP by `ps`?

Tags: process, ps, thread

How can I list information about a thread/LWP by `ps`?

Why can't I   do that simply by:

```
$ ps 10173
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
$ ps -L 10173
  PID   LWP TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

The best I can do

```
$ ps -eL  | grep 10173
10172 10173 pts/8    00:00:00 java
```

It is a LWP because

```
$ ps -L 10172
  PID   LWP TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
10172 10172 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10173 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10174 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10175 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10176 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10177 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10178 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10179 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10180 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10181 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10182 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10183 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10184 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10185 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10186 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10187 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10188 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10189 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
10172 10190 pts/8    Tl     0:00 java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
```

and

```
$ pstree -pau -l -G -s 10172
systemd,1 splash
  └─lxterminal,3194,t
      └─bash,12150
          └─java,10172 -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
              ├─{java},10173
              ├─{java},10174
              ├─{java},10175
              ├─{java},10176
              ├─{java},10177
              ├─{java},10178
              ├─{java},10179
              ├─{java},10180
              ├─{java},10181
              ├─{java},10182
              ├─{java},10183
              ├─{java},10184
              ├─{java},10185
              ├─{java},10186
              ├─{java},10187
              ├─{java},10188
              ├─{java},10189
              └─{java},10190
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to find a Java thread running on Linux with ps -axl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934747/10931455)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see just that LWP process, `ps -e -q 10172`.  If you want to see all the related threads, then you can do `ps -eL -q 10172`

So, for example, on my machine `rsyslog` has threads:

```
  PID   LWP TTY          TIME CMD
22316 22316 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
22316 22318 ?        00:02:23 in:imjournal
22316 22319 ?        00:00:00 in:imudp
22316 22320 ?        00:00:07 in:imtcp
22316 22321 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22322 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22323 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22324 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22325 ?        00:00:24 rs:main Q:Reg
```

I can see a single thread (eg 22320)

```
% ps -e -q 22320
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
22316 ?        00:02:55 in:imtcp
```

Note it shows the main PID of the process.

I can see all the related process for that thread:

```
% ps -eL -q 22320
  PID   LWP TTY          TIME CMD
22316 22316 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
22316 22318 ?        00:02:23 in:imjournal
22316 22319 ?        00:00:00 in:imudp
22316 22320 ?        00:00:07 in:imtcp
22316 22321 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22322 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22323 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22324 ?        00:00:00 in:imtcp
22316 22325 ?        00:00:24 rs:main Q:Reg
```

Comment: Thanks. I am confused by using -e with -p or -q. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512295/what-are-the-effective-differences-between-p-and-q-for-ps

Answer (score 1):

### Another way to find LWP or thread ID.

I opened vi editor against two sample files a.txt and b.txt

```
[root@docker ~]# ps -aux | head -1;ps -aux| egrep "2663|2662" | grep -v grep
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      2662  0.0  0.0 120660  2988 pts/2    S+   09:44   0:00 vim a.txt
root      2663  0.0  0.0 120660  2988 pts/1    S+   09:44   0:00 vim b.txt
```

LWP = Light weight process or Thread ID 
NLWP = Number of light weight process

```
[root@docker ~]# ps -eLf | head -1; ps -eLf | egrep "2662|2663" |grep -v grep
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2662  2624  2662  0    1 09:44 pts/2    00:00:00 vim a.txt
root      2663  2582  2663  0    1 09:44 pts/1    00:00:00 vim b.txt
```

You can see the thread id (LWP) "2662|2663" for PIDs "2662|2663" respectiverly.

```
[root@docker ~]# pstree -pau -l -G -s 2662
systemd,1 --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
  mqsshd,1197 -D
      mqsshd,2566
          mqbash,2624
              mqvim,2662 a.txt
[root@docker ~]# pstree -pau -l -G -s 2663
systemd,1 --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
  mqsshd,1197 -D
      mqsshd,2564
          mqbash,2582
              mqvim,2663 b.txt
```

> ### Another example this time.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -efL
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1470     1  1470  0   19 11:25 ?        00:00:11 /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.4/bin/mongod --bind_ip 10.12.1.132 --dbpath /mnt/mongodb_data --fork --logpath /mnt/mongodb.log
root      1470     1  1471  0   19 11:25 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.4/bin/mongod --bind_ip 10.12.1.132 --dbpath /mnt/mongodb_data --fork --logpath /mnt/mongodb.log
root      1470     1  1472  0   19 11:25 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.4/bin/mongod --bind_ip 10.12.1.132 --dbpath /mnt/mongodb_data --fork --logpath /mnt/mongodb.log
root      1470     1  1473  0   19 11:25 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.4/bin/mongod --bind_ip 10.12.1.132 --dbpath /mnt/mongodb_data --fork --logpath /mnt/mongodb.log
root      1470     1  1474  0   19 11:25 ?        00:00:06 /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.4/bin/mongod --bind_ip 10.12.1.132 --dbpath /mnt/mongodb_data --fork --logpath /mnt/mongodb.log
```

From the above output, you can see that all of those processes has got the same PID number (1470). However, they have a unique number thread id numbers(1470, 1471, 1472, 1473, 1474).

In Linux, these thread id numbers are indicated by LWP (the ps command column name is also LWP). LWP stands for Light Weight Process.

Actually...In linux, every program has at least one thread.

```
[root@docker ~]# ps axms | head -1; ps axms |egrep "2662|2663" | grep -v grep
  UID   PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
    0  2662 0000000000000000                -                -                - -    pts/2      0:00 vim a.txt
    0  2663 0000000000000000                -                -                - -    pts/1      0:00 vim b.txt
```